# finishing draw pdfbox rectangle in second page

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

pdfbox / java

Im trying to draw a rectangle starting the first horizontal line in the first page and ending draw the second horizontal line in the second page.

But, When I try to draw programmaticaly the second horizontal line in the 2nd page, It draws in the first page.

How to do that ?

**BT - Begin Table
ET - End Table**

**in my bean :**

```
pdf.BT();
    pdf.drawText(arraylist with a lof of text lines);
pdf.ET();
```

**in my pdf class :**

**class constructor :**

```
public generatePDF(Integer pageRotation){
    try {
        pdDocto = new PDDocument();
        font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        pdPage = new PDPage();
        pdPage.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        this.rotation = pageRotation;
        pdPage.setRotation(rotation);
        pdDocto.addPage(pdPage);

        this.getContentStream();

        x = new Float(0.0);
        y = new Float(0.0);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void BT(String alinhamento,Integer Width){
    this.BT = true;
    this.WidthBT = Width;
}

public void ET(){
    this.ET = true;
}

public PDPageContentStream getContentStream() throws IOException {
    contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocto, pdPage,true,true);
if(this.rotation == 90){
    contentStream.concatenate2CTM(0, 1, -1, 0, this.pdPage.getMediaBox().getWidth(), 0);
}
contentStream.setFont( font, 11 );
    return contentStream;
}

public void drawText(){

  if(this.getBT() != null){
      if(this.getBT() == true){
          contentStream.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX(), this.getX() + 50);
          this.setBT(false);
      }else if(this.getET() == true){
          contentStream.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX(), this.getX() + 50);
          this.setET(false);
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

      if (y <= marginTopBottom) {
        contentStream.close(); //fecha o antigo contentStream da primeira página.
        pdPage = new PDPage();
        pdPage.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        pdPage.setRotation(this.rotation);
        pdDocto.addPage(pdPage);
        this.setPdPage(pdPage);
        this.getContentStream();
        y = yOriginal + this.marginTopBottom;
        this.setY(y);
        this.setPdPage(pdPage);
}  

    if (i < numberOfLines ) {
      contentStream.beginText();
      contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
      y -= this.alturaLinha;
      contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( x , y - height);
      contentStream.drawString(lines.get(i));
      contentStream.endText();
      this.setY(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you in some way still work on the content stream of the first page but your pseudo-code makes it difficult to pin-point anything. Thus, please cut the actual code down to a small but still runnable sample illustrating the issue.

Comment: How do the `generatePDF` methods `BT()` and `ET()` work? Even more to the point: When do the getters `getBT()` and `getET()` return `true` or `null`?

Comment: @mkl updated code public void BT(String alinhamento,Integer Width){
 this.BT = true;
 this.WidthBT = Width;
}

public void ET(){
 this.ET = true;
}

Comment: How are the members `ET` and `BT` initialized? That been said the parameters of your line drawing commands look weird to me, `contentStream.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX(), this.getX() + 50)` - as start and end X are the same, this is not horizontal but vertical, and the end Y (being `this.getX() + 50`) appears even weirder.

Comment: Never mind. its working perfectly now with the same code Ive pasted in stack forum. Ive got a logical error in my bean method. thanks anyway :)

Comment: These X and y values in the draw line are only weird sample values for testing @mkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public generatePDF(Integer pageRotation){
    try {
        pdDocto = new PDDocument();
        font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        pdPage = new PDPage();
        pdPage.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        this.rotation = pageRotation;
        pdPage.setRotation(rotation);
        pdDocto.addPage(pdPage);

        this.getContentStream();

        x = new Float(0.0);
        y = new Float(0.0);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void BT(String alinhamento,Integer Width){
    this.BT = true;
    this.WidthBT = Width;
}

public void ET(){
    this.ET = true;
}

public PDPageContentStream getContentStream() throws IOException {
    contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocto, pdPage,true,true);
if(this.rotation == 90){
    contentStream.concatenate2CTM(0, 1, -1, 0, this.pdPage.getMediaBox().getWidth(), 0);
}
contentStream.setFont( font, 11 );
    return contentStream;
}

public void drawText(){

  if(this.getBT() != null){
      if(this.getBT() == true){
          contentStream.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX(), this.getX() + 50);
          this.setBT(false);
      }else if(this.getET() == true){
          contentStream.drawLine(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getX(), this.getX() + 50);
          this.setET(false);
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

      if (y <= marginTopBottom) {
        contentStream.close(); //fecha o antigo contentStream da primeira página.
        pdPage = new PDPage();
        pdPage.setMediaBox(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_A4);
        pdPage.setRotation(this.rotation);
        pdDocto.addPage(pdPage);
        this.setPdPage(pdPage);
        this.getContentStream();
        y = yOriginal + this.marginTopBottom;
        this.setY(y);
        this.setPdPage(pdPage);
}  

    if (i < numberOfLines ) {
      contentStream.beginText();
      contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
      y -= this.alturaLinha;
      contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( x , y - height);
      contentStream.drawString(lines.get(i));
      contentStream.endText();
      this.setY(y);
    }
  }
}
```